# scale div dynamically based on screen size

Tags: html, css

After doing some research, I found a solution to scale all the contents of a div at a certain screen size,

```
@media (max-height: 675px) {
    .card-scaler{
        margin: 0 auto;
        -ms-zoom: 0.75;
        -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
        -o-transform: scale(0.75);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
    }
}
```

but I would like to scale said div by a dynamic number (not the fixed 0.75). I would like the div to be scaled by a percent of a *changing* view height. i.e. if someone is changing the screen size, it wouldn't just jump to 75% of it's original size, but gradually de-scale in size as the screen changes. I found the calc() function, but it doesn't work as I would intend to use it. I'm looking for something along the lines of the following:

```
@media (max-height: 675px) {
    .card-scaler{
        margin: 0 auto;
        -ms-zoom: calc(vh/675);
        -moz-transform: scale(calc(vh/675));
        -o-transform: scale(calc(vh/675));
        -webkit-transform: scale(calc(vh/675));
    }
}
```

*Note: I cannot use jQuery, though I'm not sure that matters... Cheers and thank you!

Comment: just use percentages all the way around.

Answer (score 0):

Here is all the information you will need in plain javascript if you can do that, updated on screen size change.

```
window.onresize = function(event){
    var w = window,
        d = document,
        e = d.documentElement,
        g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
        x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
        y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;

}
```

Now just get the element by ID or class and edit its height and width properties as you like.

Comment: Is this possible to use in the controller of an angular app?